# problema cluster mongodb 4.0 al agregar los 3 servidores de configuración

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, cluster, mongod

al momento de intentar agregar los servidores de configuración con el siguiente comando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me aparece el siguiente error al agregar los servidores de configuración:

"errmsg" : "The hosts mongo-config-1:27017, mongo-config-2:27017 and mongo-config-3:27017 all map to this node in new configuration version 1 for replica set configReplSet",

mongo.conf:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0



processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  keyFile: /opt/mongo/keyfile



sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr

replication:
  replSetName: configReplSet
```

> Alguna idea del problema???

----ACTUALIZACIÓN----

el log que recibo es el siguiente:

> replSet initiate got DuplicateKey: The hosts mongo-config-1:27017,
>   mongo-config-2:27017 and mongo-config-3:27017 all map to this node in
>   new configuration version 1 for replica set configReplSet while
>   validating { _id: "configReplSet", configsvr: true, members: [ { _id:
>   0.0, host: "mongo-config-1:27017" }, { _id: 1.0, host: "mongo-config-2:27017" }, { _id: 2.0, host: "mongo-config-3:27017" }
>   ], version: 1 }

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, el mensaje indica que todos los alias apuntan al mismo nodo, por lo tanto imagino que estás configurando un conjunto de réplica en el mismo equipo. Si ese es el caso, debes iniciar cada servicio en un puerto diferente, ya que todos están apuntando al mismo puerto. ¿Podrías aclarar si ese es el caso? Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, los host 
 "mongo-config-1:27017" , "mongo-config-2:27017"  y "mongo-config-3:27017" son las ip privadas

Comment: logre  agregar un nodo  con rs.initiate(
{
    "_id" : "configReplSet",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongo-config-1:27017"
        }
    ]
}) eso me permitio agregar un nodo primario, pero cuando intento agregar el otro con rs.add("mongo-config-3:27017") no me permite  me dice lo siguiente:  the hosts mongo-config-1:27017 and mongo-config-3:27017 all map to this node in new configuration version 2 for replica set configReplSet no porque no puedo???

Comment: Es decir, los 3 nodos son equipos diferentes por lo que me indicas. ¿Se resuelven esos nombres de host a sus respectivas IP?

Comment: Mauricio actualice el post con el log!! agradecería tu ayuda